# How to restrict access to your website for anyone that is not logged in?

Tags: php, if-statement, session

Okay so now I am trying to restrict access to my landing page and the only way to access it should be by logging in and the code below is supposed to redirect the browser to the login page if the session is not set (a successful login sets the 'username' session)

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])){
    header('login.php');
}
```

I set up a small check that would notify me if the session is set or not

```
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
        echo "Session is set!";
    }
    else{
        echo "Session not set!";
    }
```

and then i logged in so my code said "Session is set!", yey, now let's log out and try to access this page manually... few seconds later i land on my index page and the code says "Session not set!". So what am I doing on this page then? Shouldn't I be redirected to login.php?

So mt question here is do you know why is the (!isset... function not working and how can i fix it?

Comment: BTW, make sure you use `exit()` after `header('login.php');`.

Comment: Are you trying to do `echo` and redirect in the same page? You can't do both. If you echo something before `header()`, the latter has no effect, and you should get a warning "Headers already sent".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your header call is wrong. It should be:

```
header("Location: index.php");
```

You may need to include the full URL, check the documentation:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: Blind me... Anyway, as this solved my problem it also caused another one: now I can not log in at all... Do you maybe have something on mind and should i provide my login code up here?

Comment: You need to add a check to see if the page being visited even requires a login _before_ you do the redirect. You are in a redirect loop because you don't give the login a chance to set the session before you get redirected (likely, i'm speculating without seeing code)